# Joining data from three views

Tags: select, join, multiple-views

I need to bring in data from 3 different views into my results.

View A has almost all the data I need but it uses primary keys for two fields and I need to pull in the identifiers from the UI so it looks like this:

`View A:
PortfolioID,
SecurityID,
then 20 other points I need`

`View B:
PortfolioID,
PortfolioCode,`

View C:
SecurityID,
Symbol

I need to select all the data from View A but instead of PortolioID I need the corresponding PortfolioCode from View B and instead of SecurityID I need the corresponding symbol from View C.

Sorry if this is very basic, I'm a complete newby to SQL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use joins in order to accomplish what your looking for.

```
 SELECT ViewA.PortfolioID, ViewA.SecurityID, ViewA.*, ViewB.PortfolioCode, ViewC.Symbol 
    FROM ViewA
    INNER JOIN ViewB on ViewB.PortfolioID = ViewA.PortfolioID
    INNER JOIN ViewC on ViewC.SecurityID = ViewA.SecurityID
```

You can learn more about the different types of joins [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    SELECT a.*, b.PortfolioCode, c.Symbol
    FROM ViewA a
    INNER JOIN ViewB b ON (a.PortfolioID = b.PortfolioID)
    INNER JOIN ViewC c ON (a.SecurityID = c.SecurityID)
```

Comment: I was able to get this to work. One issue I'm running into that I didn't think of is that every transaction has a debit and credit. Therefore I actually have securityID1 and securityID2 in view A. Both need to pull a symbol from the same view (c) hich has securityid as the key. The inner join of both ID1 and ID2 to c.SecurityId doesn't work.

Comment: Try this, if I'm understanding the structure of the views correctly.

`    SELECT a.*, b.PortfolioCode, c1.Symbol AS SymbolID1, c2.Symbol AS SymbolID2
    FROM ViewA a
    INNER JOIN ViewB b ON (a.PortfolioID = b.PortfolioID)
    INNER JOIN ViewC c1 ON (a.SecurityID = c1.SecurityID1)
INNER JOIN ViewC c2 ON (a.SecurityID = c2.SecurityID2)`